# Array comma separated output values in c#

Tags: c#, sorting

I want to sort this row:

> 5, 1, 6, 2, 4, 3

Here is my code:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 5, 1, 6, 2, 4, 3 };
int i, j, key;

for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    key = a[i];
    j = i - 1;

    while (j >= 0 && key < a[j])
    {
        a[j + 1] = a[j];
        j--;
    }

    a[j + 1] = key;
}

var result = string.Empty;

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",a[i]));
    //Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(a[i], ","));
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

I want to print the comma separated output value like below

> 1,2,3,4,5,6

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why aren't you just the built in sort? And why are you printing in a loop?

Comment: @jon skeet - yeah, I can use that, but I'm newbie to c#, So trying to implement the algorithm(insertion sort) by using c#, that's y

Comment: Well, given that your question is about the output rather than the sorting, I'd *start* by getting rid of your own sorting - use the built-in one. Then you can write your own sorting method, as a separate method, once you've got the output part fixed. Concentrate on one ting at a time.

Comment: The expression `string.Join(",", a)` will create a new string containing all the array values joined by commas. Just `Console.WriteLine` that; you will not have to make the loop yourself.

Comment: Also change `for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) { ..` into `for (i = 1; i < a.Length; i++) { ..`. Never hard code values into the code unless you _have to_.

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there in getting your output the way you want it.

The `String.Join` method takes as a second parameter an array, so you can directly pass it your `a` without the `for` loop:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", a));
```

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
 int[] a = new int[] { 5, 1, 6, 2, 4, 3 };
            int i, j, key;
            var result = string.Empty;
            for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                for (j = i+1; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    if (a[i] > a[j])
                    {
                        key = a[i];
                        a[i] = a[j];
                        a[j] = key;
                    }

                }
                result += a[i].ToString() + ((i == 5) ? "" : ",");
            }

            Console.WriteLine( result);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can try this way:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    Console.Write(a[i].ToString());
    if(i < 5)
      Console.Write(",");
    else
      Console.WriteLine();
}
```